# RxJS timeout on NGXS Select Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, timeout, observable, ngxs

I am facing a strange issue and hoping someone can shed some light for me.

I have a slice of my state that is getting updated on an interval (let's say every 10 seconds for the sake of this question). I want to subscribe to the selector for that piece of state and timeout if the state is not updated for that value in X amount of time. I am using rxjs timeout operator to do this.

```
@Select(MyState.myValue) myValue$: Observable<number>;

setInterval(() => //updating MyState with a new myValue, 10000);

myValue$
    .pipe(timeout(20000))
    .subscribe({
        next: myValue => console.log(myValue),
        error: err => console.log(err)
    })
```

What I am seeing is that the TimeoutError is being thrown after 20 seconds regardless of how frequently the values are being emitted.

HOWEVER, the timeout DOES work if I just apply it to the Observable returned by the interval() function.  With the below code, I never see the TimeoutError, which is what I expect to happen with the code above for NGXS.

```
interval(10000)
    .pipe(timeout(20000))
    .subscribe({
        next: myValue => console.log(intervalValue),
        error: err => console.log(err)
    })
```

So it seems like there's some issue with the Observable being returned by the Select decorator?

Comment: Your example code looks like it should work, but I'm not familiar with ngxs. Can you reproduce it on stackblitz.com?

Comment: Created Stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tq6avx?file=src/app/timeout-incorrect/timeout-incorrect.component.ts

Comment: That really is strange. I've changed it to use [connect](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ebsle?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftimeout-incorrect%2Ftimeout-incorrect.component.ts) and it works as expected. Most likely connect uses an internal Subject and subscribing to that instead. 
I recommend you post it on the [github discussion page](https://github.com/ngxs/store/discussions)

Answer (score 0):

when using **timeout** operator, you should provide a callback function to the with property. otherwise it  emit an **TimeoutError**;

for you problem, you should provide a value to **each** parameter as well.
each parameter defines The time allowed between each pushed value from the source before the resulting observable will timeout

example =>

```
test$.pipe(
   timeout({
     each: 1000,
     with: () => functionExecutedWithTimeout()
   })
)
```

refer official documentation of timeout operator for more information

Answer (score 0):

or you can use `debounceTime` it  is `rxjs` operator and it is easier

example

```
this.subject.pipe(
debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe({
        next: myValue => //do anything,
        error: err => //do anything
    })
```

resource [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime)